# Can I make Selenium work with an existing session? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently having a problem with 2FA on a website.. A way to resolve this would be to allow selenium to work with existing sessions; is there a way to allow / make selenium work with existing sessions -- instead of just making an entirely new, fresh one?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I don't think you can connect to any existing sessions

Comment: That's a shame. Do you know of any other webdrivers / modules that are capable of connecting to an existing session?

Comment: Just make python launch a webdriver session, do the log in, etc by hand/manually and let webdriver takeover from there.